# split(':',$currenttime); deprecated

Tags: php

I go this error

> Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated in `list($hrs,$mins,$secs,$msecs) = split(':',$currenttime);`

how do I rewrite it

```
date_default_timezone_set('US/Eastern');
$currenttime = date('h:i:s A',strtotime($row["orc15"]));
list($hrs,$mins,$secs,$msecs) = split(':',$currenttime);
$tha = date('h:i:s A',strtotime($row["orc15"]." -3 hours"));
```

Comment: Alternatives to `split` are listed in the docs: http://php.net/split

Comment: You read the PHP manual page [for split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php) and then look at the ALTERNATIVES mentioned in the red box

Comment: Or the TIPS later on the same page `split() is deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0. preg_split() is the suggested alternative to this function. If you don't require the power of regular expressions, it is faster to use explode(), which doesn't incur the overhead of the regular expression engine. `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php):

> **Warning**
>   This function was *DEPRECATED* in PHP 5.3.0, and *REMOVED* in PHP 7.0.0.
>   Alternatives to this function include:
>
> - `preg_split()`
> - `explode()`
> - `str_split()`

What you want can easily be done with `explode()`:

```
list($hrs,$mins,$secs,$msecs) = explode(':',$currenttime);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
list($hrs,$mins,$secs,$msecs) = explode(':',$currenttime);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use explode instead of split: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php